# Empty BLOBS - SQL Server

Tags: sql

How do you select empty BLOBS from MS SQL server.  I mean empty and not null.
For example if you wanted an empty string you could do: select * from person where name = ''.  How is this done for empty BLOBS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me when dealing with TEXT fields:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE LEN(SUBSTRING(blob,1,1))=0

Comment: The field I am referring to is an image.  Perhaps I should have made this clear.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to compare the length with 0:

WHERE [datalength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)(field) = 0

Comment: I tried this, but the datalength of an empty BLOB always seems to be greater than 0 (in every case I could see)

Comment: Is an empty BLOB always smaller than a non-empty BLOB?  If so, you could compare with something other than zero.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for rows `WHERE DATALENGTH(yourBlobCol) = 0`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx

You could also cast to varchar(max) and compare to '' but the former is probably better.