# Check for NULL varchar(max) in where condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, blob

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I am trying to run this query

```
select 
    count(ID_FILE)
from 
    MY_FILES
where 
    DOCUMENT IS NULL
```

`DOCUMENT` is a `filestream` `varchar(max)` blob column.

The query

```
select ID_FILE
from MY_FILES
```

returns in 2 seconds, if I add the `where` condition, it is endless.

There are a total of 20GB of blobs in this table, is the `IS NULL` check "stupid" so that all the 20GB of data must be scanned to check for `NULL`s?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

LaBracca,

Looks like the following post may be of assistance to you:

[Empty BLOBS - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368046/empty-blobs-sql-server)

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried to replace 'where DOCUMENT IS NULL' with 'where datalength(DOCUMENT) = 0' as suggested in the post, anyway it is super slow anyway. Somehow I would like that checking for NULL is super fast.